# Show Javascript Image fade in effect from text link

Tags: javascript

I have a simple menu which shows a different image depending on which link you hover the mouse cursor over.
Now I wanted that the images that appear would fade in so that it would look better, but I am not yet that much familiar with Javascript so I wonder if someone can help me.

Here's my code so far:

Javascript:

```
if (document.images) {


image2 = new Image
image3 = new Image
image4 = new Image
image5 = new Image
image6 = new Image
image7 = new Image
image8 = new Image
image9 = new Image
image10 = new Image


image1.src = "imgs/Categories/1.jpg" 
image2.src = "imgs/Categories/2.jpg"
image3.src = "imgs/Categories/3.jpg"
image4.src = "imgs/Categories/4.jpg"
image5.src = "imgs/Categories/5.jpg"
image6.src = "imgs/Categories/6.jpg"
image7.src = "imgs/Categories/7.jpg"
image8.src = "imgs/Categories/8.jpg"
image9.src = "imgs/Categories/9.jpg"
image10.src = "imgs/Categories/10.jpg"

}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#" onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image1.src",  onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image10.src">Link 1</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#" onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image2.src" onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image10.src">Link 2 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image3.src" onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image12.src">Link 3 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image4.src" onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image10.src"> Link 4 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image5.src" onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image10.src">Link 5 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image6.src" onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image10.src">Link 6 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image7.src" onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image12.src">Link 7 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image8.src" onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image10.src">Link 8 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image9.src" onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image10.src">Link 9</a>
          </li>
          </ul>
```

Thanks!
Nuno

Comment: How did you go with this? Did any of the solutions help? How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery fadein & jQuery fadeout for this.

Here is an example: http://kaidez.com/tutorial-simple-jquery-fade-in-fade-out/

The javascript part looks a little like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#picOne').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
    $('#picTwo').delay(5000).fadeIn(1500);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would pull all of your javascript out of the html and use jquery.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.menu li').mouseover(function() {
       whichItem = $(this).index();
       $('body').animate({ background-image: 'url(imgs/Categories/'+whichItem+'.jpg)' }, "slow");
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
 <ul class="menu">
         <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          ...      
   </ul>
```